# how to change the image of div on click of other image

Tags: javascript, html

I have two image div in HTML i want that onclik of one image other image should change

```
         <div class="image_21"><img src="pagetwo_graph_two_4.png"/></div>
        <div class="alignment"><img src="pagetwo_graph_one.png"/></div>
        <div class="image_one"><img src="pagetwo_graph_two_1.png"/></div>
       <div class="image_two"><img src="pagetwo_graph_two_2.png"/></div>
        <div class="option_image"><img src="option1.png"/></div>
        <div class="option_image_label">Option 1</div>
        <div class="option_image_one"><img src="option1.png"/></div>

         <div class="option_image_label_one">Option 2</div>
```

I want that on click on option_image_one it should change image of image_one and imagetwo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function changeImage(){
    document.getElementById('toChange').src='3.jpg';
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="option_image_one"><img src="1.jpg" onclick="changeImage()"/></div>
  <div class="image_two"><img src="2.jpg" id="toChange"/></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here the code that works for me

Comment: @PunhoonKhan where did you place the js ?

Comment: I have added js in body in script text

Comment: @PunhoonKhan post some code, because in my browser that works

Comment: may i paste all code for this or you can post your all html code here then i may run on my browser and see

Comment: thanks it worked for me but if i again press on any other button it don't work

Comment: @PunhoonKhan Yes, that's because the JS is associated with only one image. If you want to associate this to others, you have to reply the first `img` structure

Comment: i did not understand first img structure mean

Comment: If you want to extend that behaviour to any other image (clickable for change another img) you have to adapt that snippet -->`<img src="1.jpg" onclick="changeImage()"/>` to other images. Hope it's clear now :)

Answer (score 2):

```
onclick = "document.getElementById('option_image_one').getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src='pagetwo_graph_two_2.png' "
```

It would work.

Answer (score 1):

Best option is to give images some id and then do something like `document.getElementById('yourId').src='newimage'` (this should be some js function that you assign to onClick event on your first div)

Comment: where to write this code which you  have given after giving id

Comment: @PunhoonKhan : take a look to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
 <div class="option_image_one">
  <img onclick="document.getElementById('image2').src='http://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_firefox.gif'" src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_chrome.gif"/>
 </div>
 <div class="image_two">
  <img id="image2" src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_safari.gif"/>
 </div>
```

Note that I have added an ID to the second `image`.

See the live example on this [interactive HTML/JS editor](http://jsfiddle.net/877hX/embedded/result/)

Comment: I have edited question what i want look at that and then tell

Answer (score 0):

div are useless

```
<img src="option1.png" id="img1" onclick="document.getElementById('img2').src='newImage.png'"/>
<img src="pagetwo_graph_two_2.png" id="img2"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could use jQuery it would be like this:

```
$(".option_image_one img").onclick(function(event) {
    $(".image_two img").attr('href','different_image,jpg').hide().fadeIn("fast");
});
```

To use jQuery import the jQuery library by including the following in your header:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Thomas's and Filype's answers, I would suggest that use divs but put onClick for img tag and not div tag.

This is for future enhancement so that if you would like to add anything else to these divs.

Answer (score -1):

```
complete code just copy it and paste
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.small').click(function(){
            if(jQuery(this).hasClass('active')!=true);
            {
                jQuery('.small').removeClass('active');
                jQuery(this).addClass('active');
                var new_link=jQuery(this).children('img').attr('src');
                jQuery(countainer).children('img').attr('src',img_link);

            }
            });
        });
</script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="countainer">
        <img src="image/slideme-jQuery-slider.jpg" width="400" heiht="200"/ alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <br/>
    <div class="mini">
        <div class="small active">
            <img src="image/Galleria-JavaScript-Image-Gallery.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="small">
            <img src="image/Trip-Tracker-slideshow.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="" />
        </div>

        <div class="small">
            <img src="image/Visual-Lightbox-Gallery.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="" />
        </div>

        <div class="small">
            <img src="image/RoyalSlider_-_Touch-Enabled_Image_Gallery_and_Content_Slider_Plugin.jpg" alt="" height="50" width="50" />
        </div>
        <div class="small">
            <img src="image/UnoSlider-jQuery-image-slider.jpg" height="50" width="50" />

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It would be better to explain your solution and not just throw in a (to the original code) completely unrelated code snippet (which by itself isn't even working).

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.  **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)